# User's mailbox API returning different emails when on OWA vs desktop client, or pre/post SSO sign in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

In our 365 add-in, we're using the `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` API to get the user's email address, for authentication/data retrieval with our own backend (e.g. get the user's data). It returns inconsistent results depending on the user's 365 setup. Some users who have SSO setup with their org will have a completely different email returned from that API after they go through the OAuth process - meaning that it will return something like `jon.smith@domain.com` pre-OAuth, then after OAuth is complete, that same value will return `j.smith@global.domain.com`, or some permutation of that scenario. Other users will have that API return one email when they're on OWA, and a different email when they're on the desktop clients.

Since our backend uses email address as the unique ID, this causes some problems for us. I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle getting the user's email address, or identity in general. I remember reading about a 365 API that was not production ready to deal with SSO sign-ins, but that was a while ago, maybe its production ready now? I've been unable to find any additional information about that feature.

If anybody can shed any light on whats going on with the scenarios I described above I'd appreciate it.

edit - this is the SSO sign in feature that isn't production ready I was talking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

the date looks like it was updated really recently, so is it safe to assume that it isn't going to be production ready for a while?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by the users going through the OAuth process ? Please help us understand what you are referring to as pre-OAuth & post OAuth. Also, if you can provide us with a clear repro and a matrix of scenarios, we can help you better.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT 1/3 - sure: For example, when the user first loads the add-in we use the aforementioned API to check the user's email against our DB to see if they have an account with us. If they do, and they either don't have a local JWT stored, or their refresh token is invalid from inactivity, then we prompt them to go through the Oauth process again. After they have done so, and we get their refresh token and store it, if we were to use the same API to get their email again (for example during an email send - to see if they are trying to send with an alias or something like that.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT 2/3 At the time we check what email is returned by the aforementioned API AFTER they have gone through that process, AND their organization is using an SSO provider, there is no guarantee that the same email will be returned. Additionally, for some organizations we have noticed that the aforementioned API will sometimes return a different email when the user is on OWA versus on Windows/Mac desktop outlook, independent of whether they have done the OAuth process or not. 

We are unable to reproduce this with our own 365 org settings, it is dependent on the customer's

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT 3/3 SSO settings. We have many customers with different SSO providers, and the results are different for each one. The clearest matrix of scenarios I can give you would be dependent on the customer's SSO provider, but the basic idea is:

Pre Oauth with SSO provider 1- user's email is returned as `jon.smith@company.com`
Post Oauth with SSO provider 1 - user's email is returned as `j.smith@global.company.com`

(independent of pre or post oauth) 

OWA - user's email is returned as `jon.smith@company.com`
Desktop client - user's email is returned as `j.smith@c.com`

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT please let me know if you need more information, I would also love to know the status of the SSO handling feature I linked above that is still in preview mode for a couple of years now.

Comment: Thank you reporting this. We are able repro different email for OWA and desktop client issue. But We are still not able to repro different email pre-OAuth and after OAuth. Can you please share some code snippet for Oauth which you are trying?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT 1/2 the issue is the user's SSO provider. The code snippet is just using `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` - there is no special action we're taking. In order to reproduce you would need to be testing using a 365 organization that uses an SSO provider. The flow would be: user opens our add-in. If we use `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` at this point, before they've gone through the OAuth grant permission process their email will be `jon.smith@company.com`. Now, if we ask them to grant OAuth permission, after they have done so when we

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT 2/2 use `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` their email will be returned with a different value, for example something like `j.smith@global.company.com`. This is why I can't give you a specific code example - I cannot reproduce it locally as my 365 organization doesn't use an SSO provider. And it isn't a special action we're taking, we are just using the `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` API - the difference being whether or not the user has performed the OAuth grant permission action since opening the add-in sidebar.

Comment: Instead of email address, you can UserIdentityToken as uniqueId which you will get using API getUserIdentityTokenAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox#getuseridentitytokenasynccallback-usercontext

Answer (score 1):

For an identifier, instead of email address, you can get an uniqueId from UserIdentityToken using API getUserIdentityTokenAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox#getuseridentitytokenasynccallback-usercontext

We do acknowledge that there are conditions that we might return different addresses on userProfile.emailAddress and this issue has been put in our backlog.

(this is already discussed in previous comments, just posting as answer for clarity)