# How to reproduce a specific 365 add-in issue (different emails are returned when on OWA vs desktop client)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521840/users-mailbox-api-returning-different-emails-when-on-owa-vs-desktop-client-or) we have a detailed explanation about an issue with the user’s mailbox API. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521840/users-mailbox-api-returning-different-emails-when-on-owa-vs-desktop-client-or#comment98094783_55521840) @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT states that they were are able reproduce that specific issue (different email for OWA and desktop client). I would like to know which steps should I execute to reproduce this issue (since it can not be replicated in every computer but depends on some environment configurations), so that I can try to implement workarounds to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have reproduced this issue when a user's Primary SMTP address and the user's first SMTP address is different.  You can try to set a user's email addresses using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps
Be careful about changing a user's email addresses as that can impact the user's email address configuration and how the user receive email through the different addresses.